# How to remove <NUL> character in Textmate

Tags: pdf, textmate, textmate2

After copying and pasting from a PDF document there are a stream of `<NUL>` characters.

How do you remove `<NUL>` characters in Textmate a document quickly?

Answer (score 5):

The `<NUL>` character is "findable" by using the **Regular Expression** option in the "Find..." or "Find in Project...".

The regular expression `\x0` will find all `<NUL>` characters.

[image]